# Multi lingual site for one country

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I have a requirement where I have a site and the user enters the product information from an administrative end.

One of the mandatory requests is to select a country for the product before the user can save the product.

When a public user arrives at the site they need to have the option to swap between the languages. So if I arrived to the German site and want to view the site in English I should be able to change from German to English (and back to German).

I have the resource files created (German) however how do I swap between the two languages. I appreciate I may need to tweak a little more but if I can get onto the right track I can take it/question from there?

Comment: you can do this at backend-side, or front-end-side. Both can give you the same goal. If you want a front-end, you can use `JS` and some sort of using `lang` html attribute to switch between lanugauges. if you want a backend-side. You can use resources files check this out : https://codepedia.info/multiple-languages-website-asp-net-c/

Comment: Thanks will take a look at that link. Another question that comes to mind is what about the products entered into the database targeting Germany, how could they be displayed in the correct language or would they need to be displayed in German?

Comment: on the web, as long as you're using `UTF-8` encoding, it should be displayed correctly. On the backend, you need to ensure that you encoded the data correctly both on database level and in your application data processing layer.

Comment: Sorry another question but if you put these as an answer I'll accept. At present I just save the data with Server.HtmlDecode. How could I ensure the data is saved in UTF-8 in the backend when saving the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you ensure you save the data in the correct encoding in your database by configuring the data `collation` for each language, and save it in the correct datatype.

To do that you must do the following :

**Database**

- Ensure the column or database `collation` is defined to the targeted language read more about it [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15), [Oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html)
- Ensure the column datatype is designed to accept Unicode characters. (if you save some text, it should show it as is).

**Application**

in your ASP.NET Application, you ensure that you read these data from the database with the correct encoding ( `UTF-8` is a common encoding for the web, but sometimes you might need to use `ASCII` or `Unicode` then convert it back to `UTF-8` depends on the language you're dealing with).

After ensuring the `string` encoding. You can now use it on your ASP pages, you only need to control the page language you have two options.

**Option 1 :** Use `Javascript` to translate the page to another language dynamically using [html lang attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/lang).

**Option 2 :** Use .NET `Globalization` by defining the translations using resources files more in that in this [link](https://codepedia.info/multiple-languages-website-asp-net-c/)

Comment: I would go for option 2 but I'm struggling to understand when I would need to encode and how I could ensure its the correct encoding before saving data? Thx. BTW the link for option 2 doesn't work

Comment: @Computer I've updated my answer with the links as well.